# Ubuntu 14.04: Apache 2.4.7 virtualhost not working/redirecting

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtualhost

I have Apache 2.4.7 installed on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine, and some of my virtualhosts are not agreeing with me. I have 5 virtual hosts I am trying to run; 3 of them work, 2 do not. The .conf files for the two that do not work are:

**002-tmpnet.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/tmpnet
    ServerName  tmpnet
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/html/tmpnet/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        #Order allow,deny
        #allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**003-tmpcom.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/tmpcom
    ServerName  tmpcom
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/html/tmpcom>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        #Order allow,deny
        #allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Both of these return

```
500 Internal server errors
```

when trying to visit them. If I visit them through localhost (i.e. localhost/html/tmpnet) it works perfectly fine, just not when trying to use the virtual host.

My **hosts file** is:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   Eagle
127.0.1.1   tmpcom
127.0.1.1   tmpbiz
127.0.1.1   tmporg
127.0.1.1   tmpnet
127.0.1.1   thatsmybrick

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

and my **apache2.conf** is:

```
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5

# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

HostnameLookups on
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf
Include ports.conf

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

I have been stuck on this for a long while now, and I would really appreciate some help. Any pointing in the right direction would be amazing.

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

This may be a little late, not sure if you found a solution or not, but this is what i did. After spending many hours modifying my config files and tweaking my vhost, I decided to a2dissite 000... the default site and reloaded apache. Once I did this, the redirect was working as epxected. I don't know how this will unfold when you have more than one site on a server, if it will default to the first loaded vhost or ... I was always under the impression that apache had to have a default host, I could be wrong on that.

Comment: Thank You!!! I ran `a2dissite 000-default.conf` and add `.conf` to my existing files and it worked!

Answer (score 6):

Not only did I have to disable the default:

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
```

but I also had to reload apache as sudo - without sudo it was not reloading properly

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Answer (score 4):

I was facing this issue, and it turned out I had to disable the default virtual host.

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you still facing the problem?

Did you look at the error log located at /var/log/apache2/error.log. The error log is self explanatory and will give a good lead to the problem.

The error on my machine showed this (latter part of the error statement)

> .htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or
>   defined by a module not included in the server configuration

In my case the Apache module rewrite was not enabled. I enabled the module and voila the virtual host settings came alive.

Also I see that you are using the statement 'AllowOverride All' which indicates you are trying to use the rewrite module. Enable the module 'rewrite', if not already, using the command `sudo a2enmod rewrite` and then restart you apache2 `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

See if this helps!

Answer (score 0):

if you are upgrading from precise (12.04), then you need to add **.conf** extension to your virtual host config file

for example, previously you have this config

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/project
```

then you need to add **.conf** extension to it,

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/project.conf
```

and of course you have to create a new symlink in sites-enabled folder, **cd** to site-enabled folder and

```
sudo ln -s ../sites-available/project.conf
```

restart apache and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm testing the same setup:

- Apache 2.4.7 with mod_rewrite (sudo a2enable rewrite)
- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

On a clean install with the basic LAMP ([see this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04)) I use the following at sites-available (with soft link from sites-enabled)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName test.cubeinspire.com
  DocumentRoot /home/test/public_html  
  CustomLog /home/test/log/access_log combined
  ErrorLog /home/test/log/error_log
  <Directory /home/test/public_html>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

All works great only with that code. (Notice the **Require all granted** that is a new requirement of Apache 2.4.7)

When I add the following code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName redirectme.cubeinspire.com
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine on
  Redirect 301 / http://test.cubeinspire.com/
<Directory "/home/test/public_html">
  AllowOverride None
  Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then when I access redirectme.cubeinspire.com I fall into a 301 redirect loop.
This is a quite simple code that was working on previous Apache versions and there is no much said at the documentation.

So I guess there is still some bugs on that version, I would discourage to use it on a production server.

Answer (score -1):

Well, the point is this:

`IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf`

it means it will *only* includes virtual hosts files with `.conf` at the end of filename.

Rename them, or change the directive.

Ciao,
Gelma

Comment: I don't think you read the question. His files **are** named `.conf` and still not loading.